# readdir function is not working as I had expected

Tags: c

Hi I am trying to write a program which uses readdir but the entries I read are not in sorted order.What else should I look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `scandir` which reads the whole directory at once and can sort the names for you.

Comment: Ok this is a good think you told.I did not knew of any such system call.I think this is what I am looking for I see in the man page of scandir alphasort also.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Filesystem decision in what order it gives you the files or directories. If you want to display them sorted, you must first query all entries then sort them.

Comment: Ok checked with gdb and found readdir is returning a pointer to struct dirent.But These pointers point to the entries but not in a sorted order.Is this what you want to convey.If yes then let me know what else do I need to check.This sort of concept which you just said is a bit new to me.Hence I am not getting it fully.

Comment: Do you need the entries to be sorted for some purpose or it's just to have them displayed in sorted order?

Comment: Just want to have them sorted so that they are displayed in sorted order.